# How to go other component with selected select box value in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am getting the select box value. I have given below code

```
<select class="form-control" id="location" required   
            [(ngModel)]="locations" name="location"  #location="ngModel"
(change)="getResult($event.target.value);">
      <option *ngFor="let location of locationType.locations" 
            [value]="location.city_id"  >{{location.city_name}}</option>
</select>
```

I am getting value using change event. below is my code in component.

```
getResult(event){
    console.log(event);
}
```

Can any body help how to do go other component with value at the time of selecting the select box?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but inject `Router` in constructor e.g as `router` and use that like `this.router.navigate([event])`? or if it should be a parameter... `this.router.navigate(['url', event])`

Comment: Yes Richards, it's working now

Comment: @Richards, KIndly post the answer we will mark as correct

Comment: I guess you were targeting me with your comments? I wrote up an answer for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For routing import

```ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

and inject it in your constructor, e.g:

```ts
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

then you can use it in `getResult` to route to another component. Here I'm here assuming that your `event` should be the url parameter:

```ts
getResult(event){
  this.router.navigate(['your_path', event])
}
```